# Does an Artillerist Artificer's Eldritch Cannon gain a bonus to damage while under the effect of Enlarge/Reduce?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, artificer

Can the Artificer cast [*Enlarge*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) on one of their eldritch cannons to grant the cannon the extra 1d4 damage to its initial damage? Some of us were confused on the official ruling of that spell.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, Laura. While you're here, take a quick look at the [tour], and if you've got more than a moment, the [help] has lots of more in-depth information of how the site works.

Answer (score 6):

#### No, since a Tiny Cannon is not a weapon. For Small or larger Cannons, it is up to the DM.

Consider the [case](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Artillerist) of a Tiny cannon held in one hand:

> A Small eldritch cannon occupies its space, and a Tiny one can be held in one hand.

The [text](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) of the spell says (emphasis mine):

> If the target is a creature, everything it is wearing and carrying changes size with it. Any item dropped by an affected creature returns to normal size at once.
>
> **Enlarge.** The target's size doubles in all dimensions, and its weight is multiplied by eight. [...] ***The target's weapons also grow to match its new size***. While these weapons are enlarged, the target's attacks with them deal 1d4 extra damage.

Hence, if the Artifice that is holding the Tiny Cannon is targeted by the *Enlarge/Reduce* spell their weapons change in size and gain the additional 1d4 damage. It seems by description that only wielded weapons can get this bonus.

Unfortunately, The Eldritch Cannon is not a weapon:

> You've learned how to create a magical cannon. [...] The cannon is a **magical object**.

Compare the difference in description with actual magic weapons, whose description explicitly state that they are weapons (see for example a [Dragon Slayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dragon-slayer)).

Hence, even if a Tiny Cannon can be held in one hand (by description) it does not qualify for the additional 1d4 damage.

For a Small or larger Cannons, the description of *Enlarge/Reduce* is lacking details when it comes to the rules about the modified damage of weapons that are not wielded:

> You cause a creature or an object you can see within range to grow larger or smaller for the duration. Choose either a creature or an object that is neither worn nor carried. If the target is unwilling, it can make a Constitution saving throw. On a success, the spell has no effect.

See for example the following Q&A: [*If I cast the Enlarge/Reduce spell on an arrow, what weapon could it count as?*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143385/63061)

The final decision is hence on the DM.

---

#### A DM may rule otherwise.

Since an Eldritch Cannon acts as a weapon, it is used as a weapon, it does damage as a weapon and has the name of a weapon, a DM may reasonably consider it as a weapon.

In the case of a Tiny Cannon held in one hand, considering the Cannon as a weapon grants the additional 1d4 damage.

Comment: Further evidence that the cannon is not mechanically a weapon: the Artillerist also has a feature called "Arcane Firearm", which adapts an arcane focus for use by the Artillerist but does *not* turn it into a weapon, despite being called a firearm. Also, the cannon never makes any attacks anyway (the artificer makes the attack), so casting Enlarge directly on the cannon wouldn't really do anything.

Comment: I think that rather than the Dragon Slayer sword, a more on-point comparison to the Eldritch Cannon would be the Topaz Annihilator from Fizban's Treasury of Dragons, since it's a magical firearm that's basically a disintegration raygun.

Comment: @nick012000 When I wrote this answer FTD was not out, and I do not have it yet, so I can not properly cite it. *Dragon slayer* was the first example coming up in mind, 'cause my intent was to show that a weapon is actually classified as a weapon.

Answer (score -6):

## Yes.  *Enlarged* Eldritch Cannons Gain Bonus Damage.

1. The eldritch cannon is an object which is a valid target of *enlarge*.
2. *Enlarge/reduce* increases the size of the target's weapons.
3. The description and naming of both the ballista and flamethrower forms of eldritch cannon indicate they are armed with weapons.

   > The cannon exhales fire...
   >
   > Make a ranged spell attack, originating from the cannon...

Comment: By description of the spell, it seems to me that your 2nd point is valid if the target of Enlarge is a creature: *If the target is a creature, everything it is wearing and carrying changes size with it*. Moreover, the Eldritch Cannon is not equipped with any weapon listed in the PHB or in the DMG. Furthermore, in the DMG a cannon is described as a Large Object and not as a weapon.

Comment: The word 'weapon' has a pretty specific meaning in the game, and being able to produce spell attacks doesn't have anything to do with it. A magic wand isn't a weapon, and neither is an eldritch cannon. I mean, I would totally allow an enlarged cannon to deal bonus damage if it were at *my* table, but this reasoning is flawed.

Comment: This makes no sense to me, since the arcane cannon itself can vary in size by discretion of the artificer without having any other effect on the cannon's output. I am DMing for an artificer who does this, depending on the situation, to either carry it or to have it walk about like a small creature.  Canon function does not change with size of cannon.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast The damage increase isn't a side effect of changing size. Both the size change and damage increase are effects of the spell. Otherwise I would expect a more 3.5 edition approach where the size increases then you go lookup the resulting damage for the new size category.

Comment: @Eddymage the target of the spell can be a creature or an object.  The language for the damage increase is not contingent on the target being a creature.  The only creature specific language in the spell is "If the target is a creature, everything it is wearing and carrying changes size with it."

Comment: OK, I still disagree but I do see where you are coming from in terms of "this magical effect  does a particular thing"  Thanks.